# React, Graphql & Passport.js

Tags: node.js, reactjs, graphql, passport.js, apollo-client

I am trying to setup graphql with passport.js, everything seems to work fine on the server side, but on the client side when I do a check to see which user is currently logged in (req.user) I get undefined, while in server side, I do get the current user

I am running my server on localhost:4000 and client on localhost:3000.

some of my configs are as follows:

I have tried to change credentials on the client side as well as cors on the server side

Server config

```
app.use(
    session({
        resave: false,
        saveUninitialized: false,
        secret,
        store: new MongoStore({
            url: MONGO_URI,
            autoReconnect: true
        }),
        cookie: {
            maxAge: 1000 * 60 * 60 * 2
        }
    })
);

const server = new ApolloServer({
    typeDefs,
    resolvers,
    // required for passport req.user access
    playground: { settings: { 'request.credentials': 'include' } },
    // so we have access to app req,res through graphql
    context: ({ req, res }) => ({
        req,
        res
    })
});

server.applyMiddleware({ app });
```

Client Config

```
const cache = new InMemoryCache();
const link = new HttpLink({
    uri: 'http://localhost:4000/graphql',
    credentials: 'same-origin',
});

const client = new ApolloClient({
    cache,
    link,
});
```

I am hoping to be able to access get the current logged in user on the client side (react)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just in case anyone has the same issue, there are a couple of things we need to fix in order to make this work:

in client:

```
const link = createHttpLink({
    uri: 'http://localhost:4000/graphql',
    credentials: 'include',
});
```

in Server:

```
// pass types and resolvers
const server = new ApolloServer({
    typeDefs,
    resolvers,
    // required for passport req.user access
    playground: { settings: { 'request.credentials': 'include' } },
    // so we have access to app req,res through graphql
    context: ({ req, res }) => ({
        req,
        res
    })
});

server.applyMiddleware({
    app,
    cors: { origin: 'http://localhost:3000', credentials: true }
});
```

It worked for me :)

Comment: Thank you for clarifying this. I was working on this for a while with the same error about it working server side but not client. All good now!